# Link fragment not working on fixed positioned target

Tags: html

Im making a 1 page website so my menu has link fragments that move you to the correct section of the page.

My issue is that the bottom section has fixed positioning meaning that the link fragment doenst work. Ive added bottom padding to the body so when you scroll down it appears the last section is underneith the rest of the page content. What solutions are there for this?

I could just use JavaScript to scroll down the page when the link is clicked, but im not sure what the impact for screen readers or other usability devises is in doing this.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pKulL

```
<div id="menu">
  <a href="#one">One</a>
  <a href="#two">Two</a>
  <a href="#three">Three</a>
  <a href="#four">Four</a>
  <a href="#five">Five</a>
  <a href="#last">Last</a>
</div>
<div id="one">
  One
</div>  
<div id="two">
  Two
</div>  
<div id="three">
  Three
</div>  
<div id="four">
  Four
</div>  
<div id="five">
  Five
</div>  
<div id="last">
  Last
</div>

#one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
  border: 3px solid red;
  background: grey;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#last {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 3px solid green;
  background: yellow;
  z-index:1;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
body {
  padding-bottom: 300px;
}
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  background: white;
}
```

Comment: Can we see some code or perhaps a JsFiddle?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Also, don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think ive found a solution. Making the link fragment target statically positioned, and having the div within it fixed positioned seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not that `#last` is not being linked to, it is that it has a lower `z-index`.  When you link to it, that `div` remains hidden behind the other `div`s.  You just need to change the `z-index` when you click on the `#last` link.  You can alternatively use `scrollTop` to move to the bottom of screen and display the `#Last` `div` by moving the others out of the way.

To be clear about `position`

`relative` flows the element normally, but allows the position to be set relative to its normal position using the values set on the `top`, `left`, `right`, and `bottom` properties.

`absolute` places the element relative to the edge of its most recently positioned parent element. This element will be the body of the document or the element within which it is nested if that element's positioning has been set.

Using your example I have updated it so that clicking on `#last` will make that `div` appear.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready( function() {
        $("#last-link").click(function() {
            //$("#last").css("z-index", "3")
            $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height()-$(window).height() }, "fast");
        });
        $("a:not(#last-link)").click(function() {
            $("#last").css("z-index", "1")
        });
    })
    </script>
    <style type="text/css" media="all">
        #one, #two, #three, #four, #five {
          border: 3px solid red;
          background: grey;
          width: 100%;
          height: 300px;
          z-index: 2;
          position: relative;
        }
        #last {
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          border: 3px solid green;
          background: yellow;
          z-index:1;
          width: 100%;
          height: 300px;
        }
        body {
          padding-bottom: 300px;
        }
        #menu {
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          right: 0;
          z-index: 3;
          background: white;
        }
    </style>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#one">One</a> 
        <a href="#two">Two</a> 
        <a href="#three">Three</a>
        <a href="#four">Four</a> 
        <a href="#five">Five</a> 
        <a href="#last" id="last-link">Last</a>
    </div>
    <div id="one">One</div>
    <div id="two">Two</div>
    <div id="three">Three</div>
    <div id="four">Four</div>
    <div id="five">Five</div>
    <div id="last">Last</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I want the last section to have fixed position so it appears to be behind the other content when you scroll down to the bottom of the page.

Comment: If it is behind the others, that is fine. But what do you want the link to show when you click on Last?  Bring if forward?  If not, it is going to the link it just isn't showing you anything because it is still behind.

Comment: I want to scroll to the bottom of the page as this is how that element is revealed.

Comment: So you want scroll down as if it were relative but keep it fixed when not looking at it?  IF that is the case, please see the modification in the code above.

Comment: I could just javascript to manually scroll down the page (as I stated in my question). But my question was about usability for screen readers and users without javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make this work with fixed position, because when click the link, html retrieves the current position `#last` and scroll's the page to that position. Since, your `#last` div is in visible area, html doesn't scroll all the way down. You gotta have to use js to make it work.